# Check if specific input file is empty

Tags: php

In my form I have 3 input fields for file upload:

```
<input type=file name="cover_image">
<input type=file name="image1">
<input type=file name="image2">
```

How can I check if `cover_image` is empty - no file is put for upload?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can check by using the `size` field on the `$_FILES` array like so:

```
if ($_FILES['cover_image']['error'] == 4 || ($_FILES['cover_image']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['cover_image']['error'] == 0))
{
    // cover_image is empty (and not an error), or no file was uploaded
}
```

*(I also check `error` here because it may be `0` if something went wrong (ie. a file was selected, but there's no data received). I wouldn't use `name` for this check since that can be overridden). `error` with a value of `4` is `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`, so we can check for that too.*

Comment: An error code of "4" can be returned if no file is uploaded. Here is the [PHP Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: I use it like... if ($_FILES['cover_image']['name'] == true){ ... }

Comment: @Sandhu that's not even remotely valid, and is not what I suggested.

Answer (score 32):

**Method 1**

```
if($_FILES['cover_image']['name'] == "") {
// No file was selected for upload, your (re)action goes here
}
```

**Method 2**

```
if($_FILES['cover_image']['size'] == 0) {
// No file was selected for upload, your (re)action goes here
}
```

Comment: Appropriate method to me. :)

Comment: Instead of `if($_FILES['cover_image']['name'] == "") {` you can use `if(empty($_FILES['cover_image']['name'])) {`.

Answer (score 13):

You can check if there is a value, and if the image is valid by doing the following:

```
if(empty($_FILES['cover_image']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['cover_image']['tmp_name']))
{
   // Handle no image here...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
if (empty($_FILES['cover_image']['name']))
```

Comment: That doesn't check the validaty of the file. Better to use `is_uploaded_file` in combination.

Answer (score 5):

simple :

```
if($_FILES['cover_image']['error'] > 0)
    // cover_image is empty
```

Comment: Empty File means Error 4. Above fails.

Comment: @WhiteHorse that's right, if the error code is more than 0, the upload not worked

Answer (score 3):

check after the form is posted the following

```
$_FILES["cover_image"]["size"]==0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    if (!$_FILES['image']['size'][0] == 0){ //}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 if( ($_POST) && (!empty($_POST['cover_image'])) )    //verifies  if post exists and cover_image is not empty
    {
    //execute whatever code you want
    }
```

Comment: I did this one first and then check for empty on $_FILES, otherwise the non existent $_FILES threw an error.

Comment: This does not work with `<input  type=file>`. Use `$_FILES` instead and moreover `!empty($_FILES["cover_image"])` is not viable.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!empty($_FILES)) { // code if not uploaded } else { // code if uploaded }
```

Answer (score 2):

$_FILES is an associative POST method array, if You want to check anything about $_FILES You must take into account the index... I tried a lot of suggested options, and the only method that worked for me, was when I included an index in my verification method.

```
$_FILES['Your_File']['name'][0];
```

So bye doing this:

```
 if(empty($_FILES['Your_File']['name'][0])){
    print('this thing is empty');
 }else{
    print('Something, something, something');
 }
```

There's nothing like good old experimentation and lots of reading.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($_FILES['img_name']['name']!=""){
   echo "File Present";
}else{
  echo "Empty file";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($_FILES['cover_image']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['cover_image']['error'] == 0)
{ 
      // Code comes here
}
```

This thing works for me........

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="imagefile" name="imagefile[]"  multiple lang="en">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_imagefile[]" value="<?=$row[2]; ?>" class="form-control border-input" >

    if($_FILES['imagefile']['name'] == '')
        {
          $img = $_POST['hidden_imagefile'];
        }
        else{
          $img = '';
          $uploadFolder = 'uploads/gallery/';
          foreach ($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'] as $key => $image) {
            $imageTmpName = time() .$_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $imageName = time() .$_FILES['imagefile']['name'][$key];
            $img .= $imageName.',';
            $result = move_uploaded_file($imageTmpName, $uploadFolder.$img);
          }
          
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```php
if ($_FILES['cover_image']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['cover_image']['error'] == 0)

// checking if file is selected and not an error

{ 
      
// file is not selected and it is not an error

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($_FILES['cover_image']['error'] == 4){
    // the user did not choose any file
}else{
   // the user chose a file to be uploaded
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:
**Use this method:**

> First check if 'cover_image' key exists in $_FILES then check other file errors

```php
if (in_array('cover_image', array_keys($_FILES) && $_FILES['cover_image']['error'] == 0) {
  // TODO: write your code
} else {
  // return error
}
```