# How can I check that at-least one file is selected for upload

Tags: php, html

how can I check that user has selected at-least one file for upload in below code ?
i have tried with in_array, isset, !empty functions but no success
please note that userfile input is array in html

```
if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])){
            $upload_dir = strtolower(trim($_POST['name']));
  // Create directory if it does not exist
                if(!is_dir("../photoes/". $upload_dir ."/")) {
                     mkdir("../photoes/". $upload_dir ."/");
                }
            $dirname = "../photoes/".$upload_dir;

                    for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);$i++)
                        {
            // check if there is a file in the array
                         if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i]))
                            {
                            $messages[] = 'No file selected for no. '.$i.'field';
                            }
            /*** check if the file is less then the max php.ini size ***/
                        if($_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i] > $upload_max)
                             {
                             $messages[] = "File size exceeds $upload_max php.ini limit";
                             }
            // check the file is less than the maximum file size
                        elseif($_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i] > $max_file_size)
                            {
                            $messages[] = "File size exceeds $max_file_size limit";
                            }
                        else
                            {
                // copy the file to the specified dir 
                            if(@copy($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i],$dirname.'/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i]))
                                {
                    /*** give praise and thanks to the php gods ***/
                                $messages[] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i].' uploaded';
                                }

                            }
                        }
                }else{
                $messages[] = 'No file selected for upload, Please select atleast one file for upload';
                dispform();
            }
```

Comment: You should so this on the client.

Comment: You can simply check if the form element are empty or not. like this: `<?php if(!isset($_POST['elem']) || $_POST['elem']=== null || empty($_POST['elem'])) echo "No selected element"; ?>`

Comment: Have you tried using PHP's count() function? `if (count($_FILES['userfile']) != 0)`

Comment: tried both answers but still no success,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the answer, I am giving it here for other users,
I have 5 keys in html input array so array index is up to 4

```
if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][0]) or !empty($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][1]) or !empty($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][2]) or !empty($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][3]) or !empty($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][4])){
//at-least one file is selected so proceed to upload 
}else{
//no file selected, notify user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it its a couple of if's and I use a for loop as I allow multiple file uploads from a single drop down but its the if's that are more important to you

```
$uploaded = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
for ($i=0;$i<$uploaded;$i++) {
    if (strlen($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i])>1) {
       // file exists so do something
    } else {
      //file doesn't exist so do nothing
    }
}
```

You'll note I compare against the name element of the global $_FILES this is because you should never be able to upload a file without a name which also applies for no file uploaded

Don't do it client side thats a dumb place to do validation as the user can simply turn js processing off in the browser or it can be blocked by certain addons etc or intercepted and altered via firebug and various browser search hijacking toolbars etc. 
Anything like this should always be done server side!

Comment: i tried this also but if never comes true even user selects a file

Comment: have you tried var_dump($_FILES); check see that the file(s) are actually being posted in?  The above works fine in my applications.

Answer (score -1):

There are several methods of doing this with PHP (e.g. [Check if specific input file is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458553/check-if-specific-input-file-is-empty)), but with JS it's faster and less expensive on the server. Using jQuery you can do this:

```
$.fn.checkFileInput = function() {
    return ($(this).val()) ? true : false;
}


if ($('input[type="file"]').checkFileInput()) {
    alert('yay');
}
else {
    alert('gtfo!');
}
```

Comment: I am noob at JS but i will try it

Comment: Don't forget to include jQuery for this.

Comment: ok and given link is for single file inputs but mine is array

Comment: So you're using `<input type="file" multiple>`?

Comment: no i am using this <input type="file" name="userfile[]" />

Comment: Well, the easiest way would be to give it an ID but I *think* you can get away with `$('input[name="userfile[]"]')`