# if ($_FILES['image']['size'] == 0 { } returning True even though I uploaded file

Tags: php

I'm using some code from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14458594/7386637) to check if any files have been passed to a file `input`:

```
if ($_FILES['image']['size'] == 0){

    echo('test');

}
```

The echo statement should *not* fire if I've uploaded a file. However, The echo statement seems to fire regardless of whether I've attached a file or not.

This is what the file input looks like within the form:

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" id="uploadImage" multiple>
```

**I'm guessing that somehow the name of this input is not matching the name of what's being checked in the `if` statement? Maybe the array value is throwing me off?**

Comment: Because it's an array.

Comment: Yes, it's an array. But I guess I'm not writing it as an array in the if statement?

Comment: Check my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use brackets in the name of the input (which is necessary for a multiple-file upload), all the elements of `$_FILES` become arrays. You should be looping over the array to get all the inputs:

```
$file_count = count($_FILES['image']['size']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $file_count; $i++) {
    // code that uses $_FILES['image']['size'][$i], $_FILES['image']['name'][$i], and so on
    if ($_FILES['image']['size'][$i] == 0) {
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added a test echo immediately after the `for...{` line, and it doesn't seem to be firing when I attach a file

Comment: The file input is dynamically added to the form from a `<button>`..would this cause problems? I don't know why it would..

Comment: Does the form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? That's needed for uploads.

Answer (score 1):

It's set up as an array, multiple files can exist in that slot.

You have to use a foreach statement, so it will loop through every image.

```
<?
    if ($_FILES['image']) {
        $file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['image']);
        foreach ($file_ary as $file) {
            echo "File Size: {$file['size']}";
        }
    }
?>
```

You'll need this function for my answer to be of any value:

```
function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {

    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
    }

    return $file_ary;
}
```

---

You could do this pretty easily without this function, as Barmar's answer shows - but this array cleans up the default PHP in a way that makes more sense

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: This is not how the `$_FILES` array is organized for multiple inputs, even though it seems more logical. The array is in `$_FILES['image']['size']`

Comment: @barmar I forgot to include the reArrayFiles function

Comment: That's clever :)

Comment: @Barmar I wish I could take credit, I got this from php.net :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets from the name attribute in the input tag and the multiple from the input tag and you can use your method of checking.

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="uploadImage">
```

Comment: This is a good answer *assuming* the form isn't supposed to take multiple uploads.

Comment: then remove 'multiple' as well

Comment: If this answer is correct, I upvoted it back to level the score.