# checking if image is NULL or empty in php

Tags: php, html

I need to check if the image is NULL on my webpage. Currently i'm only been able to upload .png files on my website.

```
<img src="uploads/user_pic/<?php echo $first_name.'_'.$last_name.'/'.'profile_pic'.'/'.'profile_pic.'.'png'; ?>" class="img-thumbnail" />
```

so, I've been trying to do this, but I've run out of idea's on how to check on missing item's.

```
switch (missingImage) {
 case "jpg":
    <img src="uploads/user_pic/<?php echo $first_name.'_'.$last_name.'/'.'profile_pic'.'/'.'profile_pic.'.'jpg'; ?>" class="img-thumbnail" />
    break;
 ... so on and so forth
 }
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but it sounds like you're looking for [**`isset()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if specific input file is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458553/check-if-specific-input-file-is-empty)

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
$photoName = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
```

Then you check if it is empty:

```
if(empty($photoName))
{
    echo json_ecode(array("message" => "photo required"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We check for size and if there are any errors. 
Replace imageName with how your image field is called.

```
if ($_FILES['imageName']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['imageName']['error'] == 0){
  //File is empty

}
```

Comment: The if statement even when modified with the 'imageName'  changed to my imagefield still does not execute properly.

Comment: Then you are going to show us some error messages. 
If you don't get any use a debugger and if you can't use die/var_dump in your code to see how far down it executes. 

Also edit your post to include ALL of the code then.