# I can not recover the file send it to me that it is empty " !empty ($ _ FILES ["fileToUpload"] ["tmp_name"])"

Tags: php

I would like to retrieve the send files from the page `ad.php` to the page `index.php`.
I already tried several methods but the `input` is empty in the page `index.php`

I use the `JS` function `setInterval`   to check that the input is not empty in `annonce.php` but when it is retrieved it becomes empty

here are the two methods I use:

```
! Empty ($ _ FILES [ "fileToUpload"] [ "tmp_name"])

$ check = getimagesize ($ _ FILES ["fileToUpload"] ["tmp_name"])
```

annonce.php

```
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-1" >
                        <img id="photoPrincipale" src="src/images/photoPrincipale.PNG",alt="photo principal" style="cursor:pointer">
                        <input name="fileToUpload" type="file"  id="fileToUpload" accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" style="display:none" onchange="uploadImage(this)"/>
                        <span id="supprimerPhotoPrincipale" style="cursor: pointer;display: none;color:red ;">Supprimer</span>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-1" >
                        <img id="photo2" src="src/images/photo.PNG",alt="photo" style="cursor:pointer">
                        <input name="file2ToUpload" type="file" id="file2ToUpload" accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" style="display:none" onchange="uploadImage2(this)"/>
                        <span id="supprimerPhoto2" style="cursor: pointer;display: none ;color:red ;">Supprimer</span>



                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-1" >
                        <img  id="photo3" src="src/images/photo.PNG",alt="photo" style="cursor:pointer">
                        <input name="file3ToUpload" type="file" id="file3ToUpload" accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" style="display:none" onchange="uploadImage3(this)"/>
                        <span id="supprimerPhoto3" style="cursor: pointer;display: none ;color:red ;">Supprimer</span>



                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-1" >
                        <img  id="photo4" src="src/images/photo.PNG",alt="photo" style="cursor:pointer">
                        <input name="file4ToUpload" type="file" id="file4ToUpload"  accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" style="display:none" onchange="uploadImage4(this)"/>
                        <span id="supprimerPhoto4" style="cursor: pointer;display: none ;color:red ;">Supprimer</span>



                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-1" >
                        <img  id="photo5" src="src/images/photo.PNG",alt="photo" style="cursor:pointer">
                        <input name="file5ToUpload" type="file" id="file5ToUpload" accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" style="display:none" onchange="uploadImage5(this)"/>
                        <span id="supprimerPhoto5" style="cursor: pointer;display: none">Supprimer</span>



                    </div>
                    </br>
                    <span id='messageIfSameImages' class="col-lg-12"></span>
                </div>

                </br>
                </br>

                <button name="submitAnnonce" type="submit" id="submitAnnonce" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-3" style="margin-left: 4px">Valider</button>

            </div>

    <?php $imageNames=array('fileToUpload','file2ToUpload','file3ToUpload','file4ToUpload','file5ToUpload');if(isset($_POST["submitAnnonce"])){
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($imageNames);$i++){
        if(!empty($_FILES[$imageNames[$i]]["tmp_name"]))
        {
            ChromePhp::log('cette fichier et pas vide');

        }
    }}?>
```

[index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbqJa.png)

Comment: <?php
// ici le  de mettre une annonce
$imageNumber=0;
$imageNames=array('fileToUpload','file2ToUpload','file3ToUpload','file4ToUpload','file5ToUpload');

if(isset($_POST["submitAnnonce"])){
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($imageNames);$i++){
        if(!empty($_FILES[$imageNames[$i]]["tmp_name"]))
        {
            ChromePhp::log('cette fichier et pas vide');

        }
    }


}

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please confirm you use `multipart/form-data` inside the `form`

```
<form action="/action_page_binary.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

It's better to try this to check the file is empty or not.

```
if ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] == 0)
{
    // cover_image is empty (and not an error)
}
```

You can check the file `size` which is in the `$_FILES` array.

It's already defined in [Check if the specified input file is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458553/check-if-specific-input-file-is-empty)

Comment: thank you!! that was the problem I had not use multipart / form-data in the form

Comment: Happy to hear this. Please give me an up-vote and accept my answer. Thank You :-)