# If input file is empty select a default file

Tags: javascript, php, html, file, input

I want to select a default if my users don't select a file.

I checked if the file input is empty. and I don't know the next steps.
 here is my code.

**PHP**:

```
if ($_FILES['ilyes']['size'] == 0)
{
    // select the default file(name="blanc.jpeg" and the path="../blanc.jpeg")
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<input type="file" name="ilyes">
```

Comment: What are you doing with the file once it has been uploaded?

Comment: Might be this link helps to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/14458594/4781696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check file is uploaded or not by using below if else condition. if your file is not empty than upload your selected file or if your file is empty upload default image.

```
if (isset($_FILES['ilyes']) && !empty($_FILES['ilyes']['name']))
{
  //upload your selected file here
}
else
{
 //upload your default file here
}
```

Comment: the problem is that i don't know how to use upload with javascrit

Comment: you want to upload file with ajax or simple php?

Answer (score 1):

You can check file post if it empty set default image

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

      // select the default file(name="blanc.jpeg" and the path="../blanc.jpeg")

 }
```