# how to check in php if no file is selected in form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file

I send the data from a form with jquery ajax to php file.
I want to check if a user has chosen at least 1 file.
This is part of my form for the attachment file:

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="user_attachment[]" multiple="multiple">
```

My jquery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "contact.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:  new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(data){
        $(".response").html(data);
        $('.spinner').hide();
    },
                
});
```

And to check in **contact.php** if no file has been chosen:

```
$user_attachment_tmp = $_FILES['user_attachment']['tmp_name'];
$user_attachment = $_FILES['user_attachment']['name'];

// several checks if no file is chosen
if( empty($_FILES['user_attachment']['name']) ) {
    echo 'no file chosen'; // fails when nothing is chosen
}

if(!isset($_FILES['user_attachment']) || $_FILES['user_attachment']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
    echo 'no file chosen'; // fails when nothing is chosen
}

if(!file_exists($_FILES['user_attachment']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_attachment']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo 'no file chosen'; // fails when nothing is chosen
}
```

So the problem is: in each case, when no file is selected, i do NOT get the message `no file chosen`

So how can i check if no file is selected (attached in the form)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `user_attachment[]` is an array you can easily check with the `count()` function.

```
$count = count($_FILES['user_attachment']['name']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if (empty($_FILES['user_attachment']['name'][$i])) {
        echo 'no file chosen';
    }

    if ($_FILES['user_attachment']['error'][$i] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
        echo 'no file chosen';
    }

    if (!file_exists($_FILES['user_attachment']['tmp_name'][$i]) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_attachment']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
        echo 'no file chosen';
    }
}
```

Comment: just look in the console and check, what 's inside the `$_FILES` array with `var_dump($_FILES)`. Since your form states out, that `user_attachment` is an array, you can use any array function on it. Assumed that `$_FILES['user_attachment']` is an array.

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES)` gives me this: `array(1) { ["user_attachment"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(4) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } } }`

Comment: Updated the answer. Reason: The file array is structured a bit different than expected. Example: `$_FILES['user_attachment']['name']` contains exactly as much entries as files are uploaded. If no files where uploaded there is one errornous entry you can check with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by using the `size` field on the `$_FILES` array like so:

```
if ($_FILES['user_attachment']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['user_attachment']['error'] == 0)
{
    // user_attachment is empty (and not an error)
}
```

*(I also check error here because it may be 0 if something went wrong. I wouldn't use name for this check since that can be overridden)*

Copied from [Rudi Visser answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14458594/6117399)

Comment: Will not work because it is a multiple file upload and `size` as well as `error` are arrays.

Comment: well, you can add  $_FILES['user_attachment']['size'][0]